# cloud datastore transaction throughput

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Would Google's Cloud Datastore be suitable for a high-throughput application, that needs to do 1 million writes a second?  Or would a dedicated OLTP database be better suited to that workload?  Even with batched requests, it seems like the limits [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) aren't high enough.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass up to 500 entities to a single commit operation and have up to 1 write transaction per second to an entity group.

you'll have to maintain atleast 1,000,000 / 500 entity groups to reach 1 million writes / second with these limits. very unlikely that so many entity groups are logically correct for your application.